# Spark 2.0 Dataset Encoder with trait

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

I'm building a Dataset in which each record is mapped to a case class (e.g. *CustomDataEntry* with primitive types).

```
val dataset = spark.read (...) .as[CustomDataEntry]
```

So far so good

Now I'm writing a transformer that takes a Dataset with *CustomDataEntry's*, do some computations and add some new columns eg. find the latitude and longitude and calculate a *geohash*

My *CustomDataEntry* now has a property/column (*geohash*) which is **not** present in the case class, but is present in the Dataset. Again this works fine, but seems not good and not `type safe` (if this is even possible with Encoders).

I could add this as an Option field in my case class, but that seems messy, not composabl. A far better way seems that I should mixin some trait on the *CustomDataEntry*

e.g.

```
trait Geo{
    val geohash:String
}
```

and then return the dataset as

```
dataset.as[CustomDataEntry with Geo]
```

This will not work

> Error:(21, 10) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. 
>   Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes)
>   are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing
>   other types will be added in future releases.
>         .as[CustomDataEntry with Geo]

The answer seems obvious (not supported, future versions), but maybe I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encoders are not there yet IMHO, but you can use `Encoders.kryo[CustomDataEntry with Geo]` as an Encoder workaround.